# Standalone Executable for C++-OpenCV program(Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, executable

I have a piece of code written in C++ using OpenCV(Eclipse). Currently I am using a Linux machine. 
Basically i want to get a standalone executable for the same for a windows machine. Can someone please describe in detail, the steps to do so since I am fairly new to the area? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code, please. A generic answer is that you can use g++ to comiple your C++ code, but it depends to the headers and libraries the windows code is using.

Comment: The following tutorial gives a detailed description: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

Comment: @Kornel: But I am using Eclipse on ubuntu.

Comment: @LPs: It is just a general piece of code. What I am interested in, are the steps to complete the process.

Comment: ok, so you develop an opencv/linux project and in addition you would like to build a windows executable (on linux) from the same project, right? You should check the topic of cross-compiling, this means the concept of targeting a different platform than the compiler is running on.
Here is a description about cross-compiling:
http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/